# Is there a way to slice the column for ChainLadder loss triangle in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to slice the column for ChainLadder loss triangle in R.

I tried using select/filter function but it gave me these error.

```
Error in UseMethod("select_") : no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('triangle', 'matrix')"
```

```
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('triangle', 'matrix')"
```

Below are the sample codes:

```
# ChainLadder package is required.
library(ChainLadder)

df <- data.frame(Month = c("2019-10-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-10-01", 
                           "2019-11-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-11-01", 
                           "2019-12-01", "2019-12-01", 
                           "2020-01-01"),
                 T = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1),
                 value = c(100, 160, 220, 250, 100, 200, 250, 120, 150, 110))

df_Triangle <- as.triangle(df,
                           origin = "Month",
                           dev = "T",
                           value = "value")
df_Triangle

## The code below won't work on a triangle.
# df_Triangle %>% select(Month, 1, 2)
# df_Triangle %>% filter(T %in% c(1,2))
```

Output of my triangle:

[image]

My desire output:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not at all familiar with the data structures required by the `ChainLadder` package, but from some try and error approaches I can see that what in your field is called a triangle, is actually a matrix in R. You are then trying to use `dplyr` verbs like `select` and `filter` on a matrix, which will fail - they expect a data frame.

But indexing a matrix is straightforward in R, have you tried this?:

```
# Select matrix columns 1 and 2
df_Triangle[, 1:2]
```

Or

```
# create a vector of column indices you want to use for selection/filtering.   
# It seems that the column names of the triangle are the values of T
t_index <- colnames(df_Triangle) %in% c("1", "2")
# apply the vector of indices
df_Triangle[, t_index]
#             T
# Month          1   2
#   2019-10-01 100 160
#   2019-11-01 100 200
#   2019-12-01 120 150
#   2020-01-01 110  NA
```